# Angular ng-class weird result

Tags: angularjs

sorry for my english if not very good,

I'm new in angular, so I may have done something wrong.

I read some post here but I can't find any solution to the result I have with ng-class.

Here is my code:

My controller...

```
function ItemCtrl($scope, Item) {
    var items = Item.all();
    for(var i = 0, ln = items.length; i < ln; i++) {
        if(moment(items[i].enddate).isBefore(moment(), 'day')) {
            items[i].ended = true;
        } else {
            items[i].ended = false;
        }
    }
    $scope.items = items;
}
```

My html template (linked to my controller via the routeProvider)...

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <a ng-class="{endeditem: item.ended}" href="#/item/{{item._id}}">{{item.name}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 right">end:</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 right">{{item.enddate | moment:'LL'}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

What I want is list all items and put 'endeditem' css rule on those which are ended.

This code display my item list but doesn't add the 'endeditem' class on the ended item except when I go in debug mode and do a step by step execution... (I put a breakpoint on 'for' in the controller).

I precise, when I check the content of my item list, some of them have the property ended: true and some other ended: false.

Could someone help me understanding what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: your code looks ok to me,have you checked whether the `ended` property is really true for any item?

Comment: You're true Navoneel, the ended property is not set... except when I'm on debug mode and exec a step by step process... as if my list was rendered before the end of the controller... I don't understand why ?

Comment: I understood that : when I do `var items = Item.all();` , it is asynchronous method, so in realtime , the execution never enter the `for`. 
I read I have to use angular "promise", I'll look at this because I don't know how to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly with your help and some research, I did this :

```
function ItemCtrl($scope, Item) {
    var items = Item.all(function() {
        for(var i = 0, ln = items.length; i < ln; i++) {
            if(moment(items[i].enddate).isBefore(moment(), 'day')) {
                items[i].ended = true;
            } else {
                items[i].ended = false;
            }
        }
    });
    $scope.items = items;
}
```

Thanks for your help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of ngClass is

```
<ANY ng-class="expression">...</ANY>
```

where the result of the *expression* can be a string representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class names to boolean values.

In the case of a map, the names of the properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the element.

In your case you can use

```
ng-class="{'endeditem': item.ended}"
```

Comment: I tried it, it has the same behavior... doesn't work except in step by step on debug mode...

Answer (score 1):

If `Item.all()` returns a promise as you mentioned, then you need to do all the interaction with the items array inside a callback function passed to `.then()` like so:

```
function ItemCtrl($scope, Item) {
    Item.all().then(function (items) {
        for(var i = 0, ln = items.length; i < ln; i++) {
            if(moment(items[i].enddate).isBefore(moment(), 'day')) {
                items[i].ended = true;
            } else {
                items[i].ended = false;
            }
        }
        $scope.items = items;
    });
}
```

Comment: In fact, behind `Item.all()` there is a $resource service so I just add a callback in the `Item.all(function(){...my loop...})` but to make a promise with it I could have done `Item.all().$promise.then(...)`

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't use `ng-class` correctly, should be like this:

```
ng-class="{true: 'endeditem', false: ''}[item.ended]"
```

html:

```
 <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <a ng-class="{true: 'endeditem', false: ''}[item.ended]" href="#/item/{{item._id}}">{{item.name}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 right">end:</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 right">{{item.enddate | moment:'LL'}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

hope it helps you!

Comment: this is not a css issue, I found that : when I do `var items = Item.all();` , it is asynchronous method, so in realtime , the execution never enter the `for` so the `ended` property is never set. I read I have to use angular "promise", I'll look at this because I don't know how to do...

Answer (score 0):

The usage of ng-class is incorrect.
For the detailed how to, i suggest the the below link.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

In your case, 
`ng-class="{true: 'endeditem', false: ''}[item.ended]"` should work.